# How to specify geometry field in Carto Import API?

Tags: carto

I'm trying to import a CSV file into Carto via the Import API. The file looks like:

```
id,name,shape
1,"Test","POINT  ( 2673560.14000273 209469.89266413)"
```

I wrote a Python script to upload this test file via the `carto-python` [library](https://github.com/CartoDB/carto-python).

```
from cartodb import CartoDBAPIKey, FileImport

API_KEY = '...'
DOMAIN = 'mydomain'
cl = CartoDBAPIKey(API_KEY, DOMAIN)

fi = FileImport('test.csv', cl, privacy='public')
fi.run()
```

I can run the script and see the table in Carto, but the `shape` column isn't being recognized as geometry and therefore isn't making it into Carto's `the_geom` column. I'm looking at the [documentation](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/import-api/standard-tables) but I don't see any way of telling the API which field to use for geometry.

Also, is there a parameter for which SRID to use?

My XYs are in `EPSG:2272`; obviously Carto isn't going to guess that so is there a way to specify that as well?

Comment: Perhaps create a new table from this uploaded layer. During creation you can specify which column is to be used as **the_geom** and also you can repropject/transform to an appropriate EPSG.
Creation sql would be something like:    `CREATE TABLE test_geom AS
SELECT id, name, shape, ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(shape)', 2272),4326) the_geom
FROM test`    More info on running sql query from python her: https://github.com/CartoDB/carto-python